# .net serialisation different frameworks

Tags: .net

There is an error very simple to reproduce when serializing and deserializing with different .net frameworks (framework 2 and 4).
When I serialize a System.Globalization.CompareInfo with framework 2 and try to deserialize it with framework 4 there will be an OverflowException. The code is as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CompareInfo ci = CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo("de-DE");

    Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\Temp\\test.bin", FileMode.Create);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
    formatter.TypeFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.XsdString;
    formatter.Serialize(stream, ci);
    stream.Close();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream stream = File.Open("C:\\Temp\\test.bin", FileMode.Open);
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    CompareInfo ci = (CompareInfo)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

When I do this with the same version (2 or 4) it works as expected. When I save the file with framework 2 and try to open it with framework 4 i will get the OverflowException. 
Now I am looking for a workaround (since there are thousands of files writen with framework 2.0 at our customers). I tried an approach like in [How to add a custom serialization attribute that acts as ISerializable interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174591/net-c-how-to-add-a-custom-serialization-attribute-that-acts-as-iserializable) but with no success. 
Any Ideas?

I am sorry, I omitted the two lines that made may code crash:

```
  formatter.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
  formatter.TypeFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterTypeStyle.XsdString;
```

because I thought they were not necessary. Now I updated the code and it is crashing. It doesn't help to include these lines when reading the file.

Comment: I've just tried exactly what you say (serialize in 2.0.50727.6400, deserialize in 4.0.30319.18010, using the code you've posted) - and it worked fine...

Comment: Thanks for trying, it doesn't work for me. I am using VisualStudio 2010, I boiled down this code in the most simple WindowsForms application with two buttons. If I press button_1 with framework 2, then change to framework 4, recompile and press button_2, I get the overflow exception. Ofcourse I discovered this bug only until customers came with files they couldn't open with the new (framework 4) based version of our software. I couldn't open them either, finally find out it was the CompareInfo object and tried to reproduce it with the most simple scenario.

Comment: Sorry Marc, you were right, I edited my question. Now it is crashing again. Unfortunately I cannot change the old code, the files have been saved long time ago...

Comment: Now I found in Microsoft docu: "The XsdString settings are meant for high performance serialization between services built on the same version of the .NET Framework.... If you must use XsdString in such a scenario, you must provide custom serialization for types that have changed from one version of the .NET Framework to the other. "